# Grouping Row In Datatable

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have data like this..

```
ID
1234-001
1234-002
1234-003
5678-001
7890-001
7890-002
```

I am holding this data in a datatable. I am attempting to do some processing on the rows by groups based on the base number i.e. 1234, 5678, 7890

How can I iterate through this datatable and hold in new (temp) datatable

```
1234-001,1234-002, 1234-003
clear the temp datatable then hold 
5678-001
clear the temp datatable then hold
7890-001,7890-002
```

I am working on an old code base and LINQ is not available. I cant come up with an elegant solution. Maybe something to do with dataviews im not sure?

Comment: Why don't you want to use LINQ?

Comment: This is an old code base I am working on LINQ is not available

Comment: What version of .NET are you dealing with? If it's at least 2.0, you can definitely install .NET 3.5, since it runs on the 2.0 CLR. And voila, LINQ is available.

Comment: Do you load this datatable sorted on this column?

Comment: Yes I have wrote code to sort the datatable. So it is already sorted

Comment: It is not possible to just install a higher version of the .Net framework due to company policies. I know LINQ can solve this easy, but I need a non LINQ solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you don't want to use LINQ but would prefer an elegant solution...  Unless I am missing something vital in your question, this LINQified code seems to let you do what you want.

```
var grouped = from d in data
    group d by d.Id.Split('-').FirstOrDefault();

foreach(var g in grouped) {
    // do something with each group
}
```

Non-LINQ, non-var answer:

```
DataTable data = new DataTable();
data.Columns.Add("ID");
data.Columns.Add("Value");

data.Rows.Add("1234-001", "Row 1");
data.Rows.Add("1234-002", "Row 2");
data.Rows.Add("1234-003", "Row 3");
data.Rows.Add("5678-001", "Row 4");
data.Rows.Add("7890-001", "Row 5");
data.Rows.Add("7890-002", "Row 5");

Dictionary<String, List<DataRow>> grouped = new Dictionary<String, List<DataRow>>();

foreach(DataRow r in data.Select()) {
    List<DataRow> groupedRows;
    String key = r["ID"].ToString().Split('-')[0];

    if(!grouped.TryGetValue(key, out groupedRows)) {
        groupedRows = new List<DataRow>();
        grouped[key] = groupedRows;
    }

    groupedRows.Add(r); 
}

foreach(KeyValuePair<String, List<DataRow>> g in grouped) {     
    String groupKey = g.Key;

    Console.WriteLine(groupKey);
    foreach(DataRow r in g.Value) {
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", r["Value"]);
    }
}
```

I get the following output, so I'm not seeing "it only groups the first 3 and stops":

```
1234
  Row 1
  Row 2
  Row 3
5678
  Row 4
7890
  Row 5
  Row 5
```

Comment: var is not an available keyword I am working on an old code base

Comment: @NickLaMarca added a non-linq option.

Comment: can you show code how to access a field in the row where you have //do something with each group

Comment: This is close but it only groups the first 3 and stops. Can you alter it to clear the first 3 after processing then load the next set until it gets to end of the data

Comment: Had to convert it to vb.net but works great! Good job

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non Linq example.  Since you say it's sorted you can do it in one loop.

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1.Columns.Add("ID", typeof (string));
dt1.Rows.Add("1234-001");
dt1.Rows.Add("1234-002");
dt1.Rows.Add("1234-003");
dt1.Rows.Add("5678-001");
dt1.Rows.Add("7890-001");
dt1.Rows.Add("7890-002");

int i = 0;
while (i < dt1.Rows.Count)
{
    DataRow row = dt1.Rows[i];
    string key = row.Field<string>("ID").Split('-')[0];
    DataView dv = new DataView(dt1);
    dv.RowFilter = String.Format("ID LIKE '{0}*'", key.Replace("'", "''"));
    DataTable tempdt = dv.ToTable();

    i = i + tempdt.Rows.Count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help some?

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Data", typeof(string));

dt.Rows.Add("1234-001");
dt.Rows.Add("1234-002");
dt.Rows.Add("1234-003");
dt.Rows.Add("5678-001");
dt.Rows.Add("7890-001");
dt.Rows.Add("7890-002");


var stuff = from dr in dt.Select()
    group dr by dr["Data"].ToString().Split('-')[0] into g
    select new {First = g.Key, Records = g.ToList()};

    stuff.Dump();
```

Comment: var is not an available keyword I am working on an old code base

Comment: how old is it? .Net 1.1??

Comment: 2.0 there is no LINQ in the code. They prefer to keep it consistant

Answer (score 0):

var groups = table.AsEnumerable();

```
List<List<DataRow>> groupList = (from g in table.AsEnumerable()
                                group g by g.Field<string>("id").ToString().Split('-').First() into Group1
select Group1.ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: Could you edit your answer to add a brief explanation of what the query does?